# Wrong size when printing directories dimension(st_size)

Tags: c, linux

I want to the size of directories ,but for every directory the program prints "4096". How can I print the real size?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
        int i,p[2];
        pipe(p);
        struct stat buf;

        for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
                        printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
                        stat(argv[i],&buf);
                        if(S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)){
                                printf("%s is a directory\n",argv[i]);
                                printf("%zu", buf.st_size);
                         }
         }

         return 0;
}
```

I tried `printf("%llu", (unsigned long long)buf.st_zise)` , `printf("%lu",(long unsigned)buf.st_size)` but the results are the same.

Comment: A quick search for `off_t`, the type of `st_size`, says "off_t shall be signed integer types". So try a signed modifier in `printf` instead.

Comment: Or, just compile with *warnings on*: `gcc -Wall whatever.c` gives "warning: format specifies type 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') but the argument has type 'off_t' (aka 'long long') [-Wformat]".

Comment: Given that `ls` also prints `4096` as the size of directories, I'd say working as designed.

Comment: What is the "size of a directory"? The number of files/subdirs? The number of bytes used to store directory information? The latter is the allocation size. The filesystem maintains the allocation size. There is use for users.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `stat()` to find the size of a directory's contents.  It is not recursive.  It is simply telling you that the size of the directory node (without children) is 4096 bytes (i.e. one block).

Instead, you will need to recursively walk the entire directory, summing the size of all the files inside.  And take care, because there could be symlinks, hard links, and even circular links inside!  It will be easier if you only care to get the total size of the first level of the directory (i.e. files immediately within).

For more on why this is not as easy as you thought it would be, see this timeless post from 2004: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041228-00/?p=36863